# "put away in my pocket" vs. "tucked away in my pocket"

Tags: sentence

> Those things are always put away in my
>   pocket.
>
> Those things are always tucked away in
>   my pocket.

Do these mean the same thing? The first sentence makes me think of the action of putting something away, but the second sentence makes me think that the action has already been done, and those things are already in the pocket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sentences mean much the same thing, but have slightly different connotations.
*Tucked away* sounds like the items have been hidden, and perhaps are small and fit snugly into their current location.  *Put away* is more general and suggests that items have been placed into their normal storage location (which might not be hidden from view).

Comment: +1 for the mention of tucked away and hidden. _Tucked_ often has this implication: "He tucked the knife into the fold of his sleeve." This connotation is strong enough to make it into my local dictionary as part of the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences mean the same thing. Like *tucked* in your second example, *put* in your first example would usually be construed as an adjective meaning "[being in place](http://www.merriam-webstercollegiate.com/dictionary/put?show=2&t=1301436072)," as in "stay *put*."